# Where should code go that opens an EXE whilst conforming to MVVM best practices?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to implement the MVVM design pattern. I have a method that was in my code behind file bound to a button click event which opens an instructional video like so:

```
    private void OpenvideoButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Process.Start(@"Instructional_Video.wmv");
        }catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error playing instructional video");
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

My question is where should I have this code in the MVVM architecture?
Since the video is a graphical object as is the MessageBox I was thinking of keeping it in the code behind but I'm also very cautious of leaving code there.

Where should I keep code like the above whilst conforming to MVVM best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code, which "talks" to outer world (operating system, file system, database, web service, UI layer, etc.) should be placed into services - objects, that could be mocked, when you will write unit test(s) for your view model.

It is a good practice to inject services into view model, using dependency injection containers like MEF, AutoFac, NInject, etc.

Something like this:

```
public interface IPlayerLauncher
{
    void Launch(string fileName);
}

public interface IDialogService
{
    void ShowMessageBox(string message);
}

public class SomeViewModel
{
    private readonly IPlayerLaucher playerLauncher;
    private readonly IDialogService dialogService;

    private void HandleOpenVideo()
    { 
        try
        {
            playerLauncher.Launch("Instructional_Video.wmv");
        }
        catch
        {
            dialogService.ShowMessageBox("Error playing instructional video");            
        }
    }

    public SomeViewModel(IPlayerLaucher playerLaucher, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        this.playerLauncher = playerLauncher;
        this.dialogService = dialogService;
        OpenVideoCommand = new RelayCommand(HandleOpenVideo);
    }

    public ICommand OpenVideoCommand { get; }
}

public class PlayerLaucher : IPlayerLauncher
{
    public void Lauch(string fileName)
    {
        Process.Start(fileName);
    }
}

public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public void ShowMessageBox(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

`RelayCommand` (also `DelegateCommand`) is implementation of `ICommand`, which executes passed delegate. There are a lot of implementation samples over Internet.

Instead of handling click event, bind button to `OpenVideoCommand`.
Note, that exception handling like this isn't a good choice, but this is not related to this question.